# Can't click on ListView after including Spinner inside ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have used the below `XML` on my custom adapter class in row `XML` file and also added my custom adapter class. When I click to `Spinner` after can't click on `ListView` on item click. How to solved this issue?

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/exam_linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qeuestion_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="qwq"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_select_question"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/select_question" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/marks_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_select_question"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:prompt="@string/tv_chapter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

spinner in set value as a custom class.
so i don't no it better or not.
also same help to solved click on list view issue.

My adapter Java code:

```
 public class Question_list_adapter  extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;
    Activity obj_a;
    List<Questions_Details> question_list;
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public DataHolder data;
        public TextView qeuestion_name;
        public ImageView img_select_question;
        public Spinner marks_spinner;
    }

    public Question_list_adapter(Activity activity,List<Questions_Details> list_question_Details) {
        this.obj_a=activity;
        this.question_list =list_question_Details;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return question_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return question_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;

        if(vi==null)
            vi = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.qeuestion_name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.qeuestion_name);
        holder.img_select_question=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img_select_question);
        holder.qeuestion_name.setText(question_list.get(position).question);
        holder.marks_spinner= (Spinner)vi.findViewById(R.id.marks_spinner);
        holder.data = new DataHolder(obj_a);
        holder.marks_spinner.setAdapter(holder.data.getAdapter());

        if(Global_Application.selected_question_list.contains(question_list.get(position).question_Id))
            holder.img_select_question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.img_select_question.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        return vi;
    }

    }


spinner in set custom class

    public class DataHolder {


    private int selected;
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    public DataHolder(Context parent) {

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(parent, R.array.marks,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return (String) adapter.getItem(selected);
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(int selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Remove this two line : android:focusable="false"   android:focusableInTouchMode="false" from spinner properties.

Comment: now i remove android:focusable="false" and android:focusableInTouchMode="false" then also same issue can't click on listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace your adapter code with this

public class Question_list_adapter  extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;
        Activity activity;
        List<Questions_Details> question_list;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView qeuestion_name;
            public ImageView img_select_question;
            public Spinner marks_spinner;
        }

        public Question_list_adapter(Activity activity,List<Questions_Details> list_question_Details) {
            this.activity=activity;
            this.question_list =list_question_Details;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return question_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return question_list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.question_list_row, null);
                holder.qeuestion_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.qeuestion_name);
                holder.img_select_question=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_select_question);
                holder.marks_spinner= (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.marks_spinner);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.qeuestion_name.setText(question_list.get(position).question);
            holder.marks_spinner.setAdapter(new DataHolder(activity));
            if(Global_Application.selected_question_list.contains(question_list.get(position).question_Id))
                holder.img_select_question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                holder.img_select_question.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you have to play with the focusablibity dude.